# Formidable returns null and two empty objects even though I am passing the correct FormData File image

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, form-data, formidable

I have the following code that happens on submit of a form

data contains the File, and it console's just fine. When I pass it to formidable in next JS it returns empty objects for Field and Files, and can't seem to figure out why.

```
const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", data.picture[0], data.picture[0].name);

    console.log(data.picture[0]);
    console.log(formData);

    console.log(formData.get("image"));

    const res = await fetch("../api/image", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(formData),
    });
```

```
import formidable from "formidable";

// first we need to disable the default body parser
export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

export default async function image(req, res) {
  const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
  form.uploadDir = "./";
  form.keepExtensions = true;
  form.parse(req, (err, fields, files) => {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(fields);
    console.log(files);
  });

  //console.log(form);

  //   cloudinary.uploader.upload(`${body}`, function (error, result) {
  //     console.log(result, error);
  //   });

  try {
    // const result = req.body;
    res.status(200).send({ message: "hello world" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(error.requestResult.statusCode).send(error.message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using axios, no idea why it works over fetch, and I tried the content type change in fetch as well

```
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", data.picture[0], data.picture[0].name);
    axios.post('../api/image', formData, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
    })
```

Comment: because in your fetch example you used json, and json can't contain files